# Update ALL and return ALL matching documents from mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to fetch all updated documents from MongoDB using pymongo.

I tried using findOneAndUpdate() but it only updates one document.
Also tried using MongoDB js server function, but it is too slow and mostly not recommended.

```
    db.system.js.save({
      _id: "distributedTaskQueue",
      value : function(coll,status,limit,fromStatus,toStatus) {
        records = db.getCollection(coll).find({status:fromStatus}).limit(limit)

         results.forEach (function(record){
                record[status]= toStatus
                db.getCollection(coll).save(record);
         })
         return records;
      }
    })
```

The idea is to run this on 100 servers using pymongo to fetch documents for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `update_many` - http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

Find by the `status` and use `$set` to update with the `toStatus`.

Manually iterating over the documents will be slow and inefficient.

Comment: as I understand, update_many will not return the entire documents matched back to python.

Comment: You can get the `upserted_id` from the `UpdateResult` object it returns. You can't unfortunately get full docs.

Comment: Thanks. If nothing else is possible I will have to use this. I will be processing the documents fetched using python.